# Unity Shadow Sprite Shaking

Tags: unity-game-engine

Nowadays I'm working on an endless runner mobile game. In this game, I have a car and the car is moved forward (+Z axis) by CarController.cs script. The car gameobject has a shadow gameobject. This shadow gameobject is a simple sprite. I try to gain performance using this method instead of realtime light and shadow.

When I play the game on mobile device, after 1 or 2 minutes, shadow starts shaking like texture Z fighting. I read some articles about this issue and then I change Pixel Per Unit value of sprite 100 to 1. But, my problem is not solved.

Could you help me please?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Endless runner. Hmmm...my first instinct is that perhaps you're drastically changing position during gameplay? ie, at t=0 you're at `X=0,Y=0,Z=0`, but at t=120000 you're at `X=5328947.128396232,Y=2,Z=0`. At that kind of distance from the origin, floating-point numerical precision tends to get weaker. For the shadow's position calculation, do you use world coordinates, or some local coordinate system?

Comment: Your prediction is correct. I use Rigidbody.AdForce() method for moving the gameobject. I used Unity world coordinate system for calculation every gameobject's position in my game. How can I use different coordinate system for calculating gameobject's position? Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Sorry, I actually kind of guessed at that just based on general gaming/math knowledge. The situation is complicated and engine-dependent for an open-world game like GTA, but for an infinite runner, I think usually the solution is to just move the repeating elements of the world past the character, rather than have the character ever move. Not sure how easy that is.